# How to enable title bar in SDL while SDL_FULLSCREEN is enabled

Tags: sdl, fullscreen, titlebar

Is it possible to have the Title bar enabled in the SDL Window while it is initialized with SDL_FULLSCREEN mode?

Comment: Maybe that's not what you want, but can't you simply maximize the SDL window (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311818/maximize-sdl-window)? I'm not sure about it, but I don't think that's possible (fullscreen doesn't imply the title bar, by definition).

Comment: Actually I need the Title Bar with SDL_FULLSCREEN Mode ON, because close button exists only with the Title Bar.

Comment: I see your point. But, again, you can set the window at its maximum size (acting like a fullscreen), mantaining the title bar (with the X button). And, again, maybe you want a "pure" fullscreen, so you would dislike this approach, but I think that it could be a good workaround either.